# Get Document Object Model changes (Diff) within browser to modify CSS

Tags: css

Often times when I want to work with laying out frontend CSS I may play around with different values directly in the browser, and then replicate those changes back into the originating CSS files.

Say, for example, I might change a `display: flex` to a `display: block` in the browser on some column type div elements, say a 3 column layout, and then play with the widths to align them how I want for mobile.

It would be massively neat if I could just take a Diff since the Page Load of changes I've made to the DOM in the browser and populate it into a media query for certain browser width.

Usually, I use Safari for doing this as it's my browser of choice on the Mac, but I can use Chrome or Firefox if I have to. I was looking into Safari Extensions and didn't see where I can just extract DOM changes into Xcode, it only talks about injecting scripts. What about Chrome or Firefox, is what I want to do possible from a browser extension going from browser to CSS, rather than from a coding IDE going from CSS to browser and doing a sort of hot reloading?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/ ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor edit and save changed css files under a different/same name